# What should I do when it says "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody"

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with the error "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody"
and i don't know what to do.
This is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Password {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField PassField;
private JTextField txtSecretPasswords;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Password window = new Password();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Password() {
    initialize();
}/* Here*/

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 650);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    PassField = new JTextField();
    PassField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        }
    });
    PassField.setBounds(0, 42, 150, 32);
    frame.getContentPane().add(PassField);
    PassField.setColumns(10);

    txtSecretPasswords = new JTextField();
    txtSecretPasswords.setEditable(false);
    txtSecretPasswords.setText("Secret passwords");
    txtSecretPasswords.setBounds(0, 11, 131, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtSecretPasswords);
    txtSecretPasswords.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
    btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private JTextField txtMessage;
        private JTextField txtMessage2;
        private JTextField txtMessage3;
        private JTextField txtPass2;
        private JButton btnEnter2;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int pass;
            pass = Integer.parseInt(PassField.getText());
            if (pass == 3333) {

                txtMessage = new JTextField();
                txtMessage.setEditable(false);
                txtMessage.setText("Postal Code: 3333");
                txtMessage.setBounds(0, 100, 130, 20);
                frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage);
                txtMessage.setColumns(10);

                txtMessage2 = new JTextField();
                txtMessage2.setEditable(false);
                txtMessage2 .setText("Email password: 3333");   
                txtMessage2.setBounds(0, 125, 150, 20);
                frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage2);
                txtMessage2.setColumns(10);

                txtMessage3 = new JTextField();
                txtMessage3.setEditable(false);
                txtMessage3.setText("Steam password: 3333");    
                txtMessage3.setBounds(0, 170, 200, 20);
                frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage3);
                txtMessage3.setColumns(10);

                btnEnter2 = new JButton();
                btnEnter2.setText("Enter");
                btnEnter2.setBounds(175, 250, 100, 15);
                frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter2);

                btnEnter2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e) {


                        int pass2;
                        pass2 = Integer.parseInt(txtPass2.getText());
                        if (pass2 == 030303) {
                            txtMessage3 = new JTextField();
                            txtMessage3.setEditable(false);
                            txtMessage3.setText("Steam password: 3333");    
                            txtMessage3.setBounds(0, 170, 200, 20);
                            frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage3);
                            txtMessage3.setColumns(10); 


                    }
                        else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                        }
                    }/* And here*/);

                txtPass2 = new JTextField();
                txtPass2.setEditable(true);
                txtPass2.setBounds(0, 250, 150, 20);
                frame.getContentPane().add(txtPass2);
                txtPass2.setColumns(10);

            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
            }


        }
    });
    btnEnter.setBounds(160, 47, 99, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);

}
```

I know its a long one. I've tried to look through the code but I'm not that experienced with Java or coding.
 I don't know why the errors there or what to do so if you could help it would be appreciated a lot by a beginner!

Comment: You should "_insert `}` to complete ClassBody_". Probably.

Comment: You HAVE TO indent your code PROPERLY. If it was formated, you would see all the `}` missing at the end of your code.

Comment: @Gabriel. +1 for indenting. It's not enough in this case, though, because the `}` aren't all missing at the end.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using a good editor or IDE. Any decent editor should allow to "go to matching parenthesis". For example, if you use vi, position the cursor on a brace and type "%" to go to the matching one. You can use this to verify that parenthesis are matching as you expect.

IDEs such as Eclipse or IntelliJ allow you to reformat code, which will also help you spot where you're missing a closing brace. They also offer other invaluable features when programming in Java, so I strongly suggest spending the time to install and learn one.

This said, you're missing a close brace right before the "And here" comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use auto-indent from your text editor, you notice that the last '}' is still indented by one tab.
It means there are more `{` than `}`.
With a good IDE (e.g. Eclipse) it's easier to find out where it should be added (Once at the end, once before the last `/* And here */` comment). Note that the first error shown by Eclipse isn't the right location in this case.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Password
{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField PassField;
    private JTextField txtSecretPasswords;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Password window = new Password();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Password() {
        initialize();
    }/* Here */

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 650);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        PassField = new JTextField();
        PassField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            }
        });
        PassField.setBounds(0, 42, 150, 32);
        frame.getContentPane().add(PassField);
        PassField.setColumns(10);

        txtSecretPasswords = new JTextField();
        txtSecretPasswords.setEditable(false);
        txtSecretPasswords.setText("Secret passwords");
        txtSecretPasswords.setBounds(0, 11, 131, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtSecretPasswords);
        txtSecretPasswords.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
        btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private JTextField txtMessage;
            private JTextField txtMessage2;
            private JTextField txtMessage3;
            private JTextField txtPass2;
            private JButton btnEnter2;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int pass;
                pass = Integer.parseInt(PassField.getText());
                if (pass == 5441) {

                    txtMessage = new JTextField();
                    txtMessage.setEditable(false);
                    txtMessage.setText("Postal Code: 42658");
                    txtMessage.setBounds(0, 100, 130, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage);
                    txtMessage.setColumns(10);

                    txtMessage2 = new JTextField();
                    txtMessage2.setEditable(false);
                    txtMessage2.setText("Email password: Vauxhal1");
                    txtMessage2.setBounds(0, 125, 150, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage2);
                    txtMessage2.setColumns(10);

                    txtMessage3 = new JTextField();
                    txtMessage3.setEditable(false);
                    txtMessage3.setText("Steam password: Vauxhal12");
                    txtMessage3.setBounds(0, 170, 200, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage3);
                    txtMessage3.setColumns(10);

                    btnEnter2 = new JButton();
                    btnEnter2.setText("Enter");
                    btnEnter2.setBounds(175, 250, 100, 15);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter2);

                    btnEnter2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e) {

                            int pass2;
                            pass2 = Integer.parseInt(txtPass2.getText());
                            if (pass2 == 030303) {
                                txtMessage3 = new JTextField();
                                txtMessage3.setEditable(false);
                                txtMessage3.setText("Steam password: Vauxhal12");
                                txtMessage3.setBounds(0, 170, 200, 20);
                                frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage3);
                                txtMessage3.setColumns(10);


                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }/* And here */);

                    txtPass2 = new JTextField();
                    txtPass2.setEditable(true);
                    txtPass2.setBounds(0, 250, 150, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPass2);
                    txtPass2.setColumns(10);

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                }


            }
        });
        btnEnter.setBounds(160, 47, 99, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);

    }
}
```

PS: If you just want to use a basic text editor, Java is the wrong language. Either use Java + full IDE (Netbeans or Eclipse), or Ruby/Python with pluma/notepad2/vim/...

Answer (score 0):

Insert `}` at the start of line 122 and at the end of code to complete `classBody`.

But you should really consider Roberto Attia's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an IDE in order to be able to indent your code and see any missing curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as many others have suggested here, is in the balancing of the braces, meaning each `{` opens a block of code and thus needs a matching `}` to close that block of code.
IDEs do make it easier to do this matching for you, many free text editors are available to do this matching for you.

So a few changes to your code:

This line `}/* And here*/);` delete `/* And here*/` and replace it with `}`.

Next, the main class `public class Password` needs to be closed on the last line with a `}`.

Lastly, since the `btnEnter2` needs to override the `addActionListener` abstract method, you have a typo in line `public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e) {`, `actionPreformed` should be spelled `actionPerformed` to successfully override the `addActionListener` anonymous method.

The final code should resemble:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Password {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField PassField;
    private JTextField txtSecretPasswords;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Password window = new Password();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Password() {
        initialize();
    }/* Here*/

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 650);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        PassField = new JTextField();
        PassField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            }
        });
        PassField.setBounds(0, 42, 150, 32);
        frame.getContentPane().add(PassField);
        PassField.setColumns(10);

        txtSecretPasswords = new JTextField();
        txtSecretPasswords.setEditable(false);
        txtSecretPasswords.setText("Secret passwords");
        txtSecretPasswords.setBounds(0, 11, 131, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtSecretPasswords);
        txtSecretPasswords.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
        btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private JTextField txtMessage;
            private JTextField txtMessage2;
            private JTextField txtMessage3;
            private JTextField txtPass2;
            private JButton btnEnter2;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int pass;
                pass = Integer.parseInt(PassField.getText());
                if (pass == 5441) {

                    txtMessage = new JTextField();
                    txtMessage.setEditable(false);
                    txtMessage.setText("Postal Code: 42658");
                    txtMessage.setBounds(0, 100, 130, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage);
                    txtMessage.setColumns(10);

                    txtMessage2 = new JTextField();
                    txtMessage2.setEditable(false);
                    txtMessage2 .setText("Email password: Vauxhal1");   
                    txtMessage2.setBounds(0, 125, 150, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage2);
                    txtMessage2.setColumns(10);

                    txtMessage3 = new JTextField();
                    txtMessage3.setEditable(false);
                    txtMessage3.setText("Steam password: Vauxhal12");   
                    txtMessage3.setBounds(0, 170, 200, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage3);
                    txtMessage3.setColumns(10);

                    btnEnter2 = new JButton();
                    btnEnter2.setText("Enter");
                    btnEnter2.setBounds(175, 250, 100, 15);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter2);

                    btnEnter2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                            int pass2;
                            pass2 = Integer.parseInt(txtPass2.getText());
                            if (pass2 == 030303) {
                                txtMessage3 = new JTextField();
                                txtMessage3.setEditable(false);
                                txtMessage3.setText("Steam password: Vauxhal12");   
                                txtMessage3.setBounds(0, 170, 200, 20);
                                frame.getContentPane().add(txtMessage3);
                                txtMessage3.setColumns(10); 


                        }
                            else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    txtPass2 = new JTextField();
                    txtPass2.setEditable(true);
                    txtPass2.setBounds(0, 250, 150, 20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPass2);
                    txtPass2.setColumns(10);

                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");
                }


            }
        });
        btnEnter.setBounds(160, 47, 99, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnter);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.